# Docker volumes data disapear after docker-stop but are available through SFTP

Tags: docker, debian, docker-compose

I deploy a set of docker container with docker-compose v3.

I have a container with the transmission torrent client, this container has a mounted volume for the download folder.

I deployed my container, everything was running smoothly I had a lot of downloaded files.

I decided to add a new container to my docker compose, I do:

`docker-compose stop`

`docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

`docker-compose up -d                 # with new docker-compose.yml`

Now, all the container are working perfectly again, the webservices are up, but when I go to the download folder using the command line, the folder is **empty**.

I tried everything docker stop, start... nothing. I'm root user.

But when I do a `df -h` I see that my hard drive is still full and that the my data is still there somewhere.

I used a desktop SFTP client to connect to my server and I then see that all my data is still in the downloads folder.

When I switch from root user to the user PUID=1003 (the user that I give to my containers), I can see the files again.

I don't understand whats happening why am I not able to see my files in the command line (they are not hidden), why my docker-compose is not mounting the volumes ?

Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
plex:
    image: plexinc/pms-docker:latest
    networks:
    - web
    environment:
    - PLEX_UID=1003
    - PLEX_GID=1003
    volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - ./media/transmission/downloads/:/data
    - ./media/plex/config/:/config
    - /tmp/transcode/:/transcode
    labels:
    - "traefik.enable=true"
    - "traefik.backend=plex"
    - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:plex.domain.tld"
    - "traefik.port=32400"
    - "traefik.docker.network=web"
    depends_on:
    - transmission

transmission:
    image: linuxserver/transmission:latest
    networks:
    - web
    environment:
    - PUID=1003
    - PGID=1003
    volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - ./media/transmission/config/:/config
    - ./media/transmission/downloads/:/downloads
    labels:
    - "traefik.enable=true"
    - "traefik.backend=transmission"
    - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:bt.domain.tld"
    - "traefik.port=9091"
    - "traefik.docker.network=web"
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Since you are using folder mounts, the files should be there

Comment: Yes, this is extremely strange, I stop everything docker related and go back to the folder look into it using the CLI and it's empty. Going back to my SFTP gui everything is there, I'm even able to move it to other folders where it appears in the CLI.

Comment: You said `When I switch from root user to the user PUID=1003 (the user that I give to my containers), I can see the files again.` this is on the host machine or inside the container?

Comment: @TarunLalwani on the host machine

Comment: I think even ls works based on user permissions. So do `chmod 777 -R directory` and see if then you see files in it?